# vk api если ответ совпадает, если нет

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как сделать так, чтобы, если приходит ответ сервера от **VK API** `{"response":1}`, то выполнялся код который в `if`. Если это не так то `else`.

Не рабочий код, при всех значениях он выводит то что в `if`.

```
<?php 

if (!isset($_REQUEST)) { 
  return; 
} 

//Ключ доступа сообщества 
$token = 'My key'; 

//Получаем и декодируем уведомление 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 

//Проверяем, что находится в поле "type" 
switch ($data->type) { 

//Если это уведомление о новом сообщении... 
  case 'message_new': 
    //...получаем id его автора 
    $user_id = $data->object->user_id; 

//С помощью groups.isMember и токена сообщества получаем ответ
    $request_params = array( 
      'group_id' => 147190614, 
      'user_id' => $user_id, 
      'access_token' => $token, 
      'v' => '5.0' 
    ); 

$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);

$getting = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/groups.isMember?'. $get_params);

if ($getting = 1) {
    //С помощью messages.send и токена сообщества отправляем ответное сообщение 
    $request_params = array( 
      'message' => "Hello, asddsa!", 
      'user_id' => $user_id, 
      'access_token' => $token, 
      'v' => '5.0' 
    ); 

$get_params = http_build_query($request_params); 

file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params); 
} else {
    //С помощью messages.send и токена сообщества отправляем ответное сообщение 
    $request_params = array( 
      'message' => "GODBAY!", 
      'user_id' => $user_id, 
      'access_token' => $token, 
      'v' => '5.0' 
    ); 

$get_params = http_build_query($request_params); 

file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params); 
}

//Возвращаем "ok" серверу Callback API 
    echo('ok'); 

break; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Не  `=`, а `==` в `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Конструкция `$getting = 1` является присваиванием и, в данном случае, проверка получается такая `if(1){...`, а `1==true`.
2. После

   ```
   $getting = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/groups.isMember?'. $get_params);
   ```

переменная `$gettings` будет равна полному ответу, то есть `{"response":1}`

Следовательно вам надо либо сравнивать так `if($gettings=='{"response":1}'){...`, что неправильно, либо сперва достать из json'а значение ответа. Смотрите в сторону функции `json_decode`